# background is not support in ie8 only?

Tags: html, css

I used html code header type and put css for it. then take a background for it. It is well functioning in google crome, mozilla, safari but Background is not working in ie 8 from header.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>ASI India Travels</title>
<style>
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, article, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p,
time, mark, audio, video {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border:0;
   outline:0;
   vertical-align:baseline;
}  
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { 
    display:block;
}
body {
  background-color:#666666;
 }
.container {
  width:875px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
header{ }
#header {
  background-color:#009966;
  height:275px;
}
</style>
</head>

<body>
 <header id="header">
   <div class="container">
    header
   </div>
 </header>
</body>
```

Can you please anyone resolve this problem? Thanks in Advance...

Comment: Because `<header>` is not a valid markup in IE<9?

Answer (score 2):

You can't style HTML5 markup in IE8 and below.

> Internet Explorer <9 doesn't know how to render CSS on elements that
>   it doesn't recognize.

[Learn more](http://ejohn.org/blog/html5-shiv/)

You need a Javascript polyfill called [**html5shiv**](https://code.google.com/p/html5shiv/).

Answer (score 0):

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en" class="no-js">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge,chrome=1">
<title>ASI India Travels</title>
<!--[if lt IE 9]>
<script src="//html5shiv.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/html5.js"></script>
<![endif]--> 
<style>
html, body, div, span, object, iframe, article, 
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section, summary,
h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, p,
time, mark, audio, video {
   margin:0;
   padding:0;
   border:0;
   outline:0;
   vertical-align:baseline;
}  
article, aside, details, figcaption, figure,
footer, header, hgroup, menu, nav, section { 
    display:block;
}
body {
  background-color:#666666;
 }
.container {
  width:875px;
  margin-left:auto;
  margin-right:auto;
}
header{ }
#header {
  background-color:#009966;
  height:275px;
}
</style>

</head>

<body>
 <header id="header">
   <div class="container">
    header
   </div>
 </header>
</body>
```

You have to support html5 tags in your document. In this case your using `header` tag which is a html5 element.

You can find more info about html5 via visiting [this](http://html5doctor.com/) site.

Take a look at [jsFiddle example](http://jsfiddle.net/agriboz/cGK4K/1/)

Answer (score 0):

try this:

```
background-color:#xxxxx\0/;
```

put `"\0/"` this is one of the hacks in IE8
you can use this link fo more info: [IE Hacks](http://css-tricks.com/how-to-create-an-ie-only-stylesheet/)

Answer (score 0):

It is because of your `<header>` tag. 
You can include this javascript to work HTML5 tags in IE 8

```
<script type="text/javascript">
 document.createElement('header');
</script>
```

Hope this will help

Comment: this is workable but i want this form html only. how can we identify css3. I donot want to use Js. Thanks for all.

Answer (score 0):

You need to do 2 things:

1. add a script (modernizr) that makes this html5 elements for IE8. [You have to download the script](http://modernizr.com/download/)
2. add CSS to make  a block level element (that you have allready)

Add this to your `<head>`

```
<script src="js/modernizr-1.7.min.js"></script>
```

Then you can use in your CSS:

```
 header{
  background-color:#009966;
  height:275px;
```

Comment: you can thank me by voting and/or set this as correct answer.